# Flink streaming job switched to failed status

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I hava a 8 nodes Flink cluster and a 5 nodes Kafka cluster to run a WordCount job. In the first case, lot of data is generated and pushed to Kafka and then Flink job is launched. Everything works fine in this case.
While in the second case, Flink streaming job is launched first, then data  is produced into Kafka topic. In this case, the Flink job is usually switched to failed status. Some times it fails immediately after the job is launched. Sometimes it fails several minutes after the job is launched.

```
org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.exception.RemoteTransportException: Error at remote task manager 'worker1/192.168.1.38:35240'.
at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.PartitionRequestClientHandler.decodeMsg(PartitionRequestClientHandler.java:241)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.PartitionRequestClientHandler.channelRead(PartitionRequestClientHandler.java:164)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:244)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.partition.ProducerFailedException
at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.PartitionRequestQueue.writeAndFlushNextMessageIfPossible(PartitionRequestQueue.java:164)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.PartitionRequestQueue.userEventTriggered(PartitionRequestQueue.java:96)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:279)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:265)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.userEventTriggered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:108)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:279)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:265)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.userEventTriggered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:108)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:279)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:265)
at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.userEventTriggered(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:108)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeUserEventTriggered(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:279)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.access$500(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:32)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext$6.run(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:270)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:358)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:357)
... 2 more
01/24/2016 22:21:32 Keyed Reduce -> Sink: Unnamed(29/32) switched to FAILED

org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.exception.RemoteTransportException: Error at remote task manager 'worker1/192.168.1.38:35240'.
at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.PartitionRequestClientHandler.decodeMsg(PartitionRequestClientHandler.java:241)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.io.network.netty.PartitionRequestClientHandler.channelRead(PartitionRequestClientHandler.java:164)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.handler.codec.MessageToMessageDecoder.channelRead(MessageToMessageDecoder.java:103)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.channelRead(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:244)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:308)
at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:294)
at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:846)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:131)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:468)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:382)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:112)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In the log file of worker4, the error is:

```
23:03:43,786 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Source: Custom Source -> Map -> Flat Map -> Map (20/32) switched to FAILED with exception.
java.lang.Exception: Error while fetching from broker:
Exception for partition 19: kafka.common.UnknownException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:383)
    at kafka.common.ErrorMapping$.exceptionFor(ErrorMapping.scala:86)
    at kafka.common.ErrorMapping.exceptionFor(ErrorMapping.scala)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.LegacyFetcher$SimpleConsumerThread.run(LegacyFetcher.java:406)

    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.LegacyFetcher.run(LegacyFetcher.java:242)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer.run(FlinkKafkaConsumer.java:397)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:58)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask.run(SourceStreamTask.java:55)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:218)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:584)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error while fetching from broker:
Exception for partition 19: kafka.common.UnknownException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:383)
    at kafka.common.ErrorMapping$.exceptionFor(ErrorMapping.scala:86)
    at kafka.common.ErrorMapping.exceptionFor(ErrorMapping.scala)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.LegacyFetcher$SimpleConsumerThread.run(LegacyFetcher.java:406)

    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.LegacyFetcher$SimpleConsumerThread.run(LegacyFetcher.java:422)
```

Before this UnknowException, there are some logs related to zookeeper:

```
08:58:47,720 INFO  org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread                                 - Terminate ZkClient event thread.
08:58:47,737 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper                                - Session: 0x15277fbb7c70020 closed
08:58:47,737 INFO  org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn                               - EventThread shut down
08:58:47,737 INFO  org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task                     - Source: Custom Source -> Map -> Flat Map -> Map (6/32) switched to FAILED with exception.
```

Comment: Which version do you use (Flink, Kafka, Flink-Kafka-Connector)?

Comment: flink-0.10.1, kafka-0.8.2.1, flink-connector-kafka-0.10.1

Comment: The kafka consumer class used in the program is `FlinkKafkaConsumer082`

Answer (score 0):

The root cause of the error is

```
Exception for partition 19: kafka.common.UnknownException
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:383)
    at kafka.common.ErrorMapping$.exceptionFor(ErrorMapping.scala:86)
    at kafka.common.ErrorMapping.exceptionFor(ErrorMapping.scala)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.LegacyFetcher$SimpleConsumerThread.run(LegacyFetcher.java:406)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.LegacyFetcher.run(LegacyFetcher.java:242)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer.run(FlinkKafkaConsumer.java:397)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:58)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask.run(SourceStreamTask.java:55)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.StreamTask.invoke(StreamTask.java:218)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.Task.run(Task.java:584)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

The `UnknownException` is most likely triggered by this error on the Kafka side:

```
[2016-01-25 12:45:30,195] ERROR [Replica Manager on Broker 2]: Error when processing fetch request for partition [WordCount,4] offset 335517 from consumer with correlation id 0. Possible cause: Attempt to read with a maximum offset (335515) less than the start offset (335517). (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
```

I've filed a JIRA in Flink for the problem: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-3288

Comment: In worker1, the error is similar. It shows the error is from worker4(RemoteTransportException). I saw the error in worker4 is a little different and updated it in the question. Thanks

Comment: Before this UnknowException, there are some log related to zookeeper, do you think it is related to this error? The log is updated in my question

Comment: Mh, the ZK logs indicate that it is shutting down for some reason. There are no other suspicious log entries?
Did you have a chance to check the broker log?

Comment: There is no error message in Kafka broker log. The funny thing is after the job is failed. My data generator will run continuously. Then I launch the streaming job again, it works fine.

Comment: Are you only passing the required properties into the FlinkKafkaConsumer, or any additional?
Are you reading from multiple topics, or only from one?
Do you have multiple FlinkKafkaConsumers or only one in the job?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101593/discussion-between-rmetzger-and-yangjun-wang).

Comment: `auto.commit.enable` is set to `false` in the program. In this case, there is only one topic with 32 partitions. 8 work nodes each with 4 task slots will read from the Kafka topic. It means that there would be 32 FlinkKafkaConsumers working at the same time. Among my tests, when the data is generated with low speed, the program works fine.